# How to sort outer map by nested map value

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

i got a problem with Java 8 sorted method.

I got following structure:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is sort outer map first by outer map's key (forced order), then by sum of inner map values (Longs), and put it into Map.Entry list in correct order. I managed to sort it with first condition, but I'm unable to make it work with second condition (thenComparing method) - there is type error.

```
queryResult.allCountersArray = queryResult.allCounters.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Map<String, Long>>comparingByKey(Comparator.comparing(term -> term.getSortingKey()))
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.<String, Map<String, Long>>comparingByValue(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue()))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());


Error:(87, 49) java: no suitable method found for comparingByValue(java.util.Comparator<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>>)
    method java.util.Map.Entry.<K,V>comparingByValue() is not applicable
      (explicit type argument java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> does not conform to declared bound(s) java.lang.Comparable<? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>>)
    method java.util.Map.Entry.<K,V>comparingByValue(java.util.Comparator<? super V>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.Comparator<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>> cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>>)
```

Comment: *then by inner map value...*: the inner map will have multiple key/value pairs, technically. Which one do you want to use in the sort?

Comment: I failed hard on explaining that. I try to sort it by sum of these inner Longs. I'm editing question now.

Comment: Maybe add an example (input --> expected output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `comparingByValue` in this case because you don't want to sort by individual entries of the inner map.

The best you can do is:

```
List<Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>> result = queryResult.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>::getKey)
                .thenComparingLong(e -> e.getValue()
                        .values()
                        .stream()
                        .mapToLong(i -> i)
                        .sum()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or

```
List<Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>> result2 = queryResult.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Entry.<String, Map<String, Long>>comparingByKey()
                .thenComparingLong(e -> e.getValue()
                        .values()
                        .stream()
                        .mapToLong(i -> i)
                        .sum()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @voidmat I'm sure you can just add `.reversed()` to the `thenComparing()` expression (can't test it right now, but should theoretically work)

Comment: I used just thenComparing with first argument being your function (argument from thenComparingLong) and second argument Comparator.reverseOrder().

Comment: The OP *could* use `comparingByValue` when providing the right value comparator, which would differ from your comparator only by not needing the first `getValue()` call. But since all keys of a `Map` are distinct, the entire secondary sort criteria is obsolete anyway when using `Entry.<String, Map<String, Long>>comparingByKey()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map = new HashMap<>();

final List<Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>> sorted = 
    map.entrySet().stream().sorted((a,  b) -> Long.compare(
        a.getValue().values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum(),
        b.getValue().values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```